# Change field/attribute value in model - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have the table `products` with `price` column. In model I would like to do something like this:

```
public function getPriceAttribute()
{
    return number_format($this->price);
}
```

So in view I use

```
{{ $property->price }} &euro;
```

and get the value `200` instead `200.00` how is decimal from database.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why can't you just use (float)$property->price ?

Comment: In view? Cuz in future if I wanna change something to change in one place not in x pages :).

Comment: You can create a helper function for the number_format and call it from View.

Comment: There must be a way from model, and not to create a new helper only for this ...

Comment: Yes, you can do this from the Model. It is called eloquent Attribute Casting. Did you try this?

Comment: You need to add the `decimals` parameter to the `number_format` fuction call: `return number_format($this->price, 2);`

Comment: Not necessary, is optional. I posted answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is what solved my problem:

```
public function getPriceAttribute()
{
    return number_format($this->attributes['price']);
}
```

This will overwrite the `$property->price` value (as per comments)

Comment: Will this overload `$property->price` ?

Comment: @Laerte to clarify, yes, this will.

Comment: @Laerte thats why it's not a good idea only for fomratting purposes. A global helper would be a good ide, or if you prefer accessors, a custom one is great. Like pubf getFormattedPriceAttribute() and $property->formatted_price

Answer (score 4):

You can do so by passing original value as argument, like this:

```
public function getPriceAttribute($price)
{
   return number_format($price);
}
```

You can find more about Mutators (and Casting) here:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators